# Chrome extension with facebook block

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like you to help me understand why my code is not working.
I want to make one extension that when i join m.facebook.com it will redirect me to another page that i want.

Let me show you my code until now.

```
var host = "http://www.google.com";          // here you put the URL that you want to be redirected 



chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
         return {redirectUrl: host + details.url.match(/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+([\S\s]*)/)[1]};              //where it says "host" you put the name of the var that you have set above to the URL that you want to be redirected


    },
    {
        urls: [
            "*://www.facebook.com/*"                    // here you put the URL that you want to block.
        ],
        types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other"]
    },
    ["blocking"]
);
```

manifest

```
{
    "name": "Facebook Notification Block",
    "description": "Block Notification",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
                    "*://facebook.com/*",
            "*://www.facebook.com/*",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ]
}
```

This code is working perfect BUT only for www.facebook.com
(when i try to join www.facebook.com it redirects me to google.com)
When i replace to

```
urls: [
            "*://m.facebook.com/*"                    // here you put the URL that you want to block.
        ],
```

it doesnt work, and it joins m.facebook.com

Can anyone help me???

i've also tried to put

```
"m.facebook.com/"
```

but still not working.
Thanks for your time reading this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    "name": "Facebook Notification Block",
    "description": "Block Notification",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
                    "*://facebook.com/*",
                     "*://m.facebook.com/*",
            "*://www.facebook.com/*",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ]
}
```

How stupid i am... forgot to add m.facebook.com to the permissions.
Now works fine.